Unable to install couchbase server on kubernetes cluster (memcached issue)
I am trying to deploy couchbase server on my local kind cluster (podman) using the offical couchbase docker image.
This is my couchbase-cluster.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
name: couchbase
labels:
app: couchbase
env: dev
spec:
replicas: 1
selector:
matchLabels:
app: couchbase
env: dev
template:
metadata:
labels:
app: couchbase
env: dev
spec:
containers:
- name: couchbase
image: couchbase/server:enterprise-7.2.5
imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
ports:
- name: first
containerPort: 8091
- name: second
containerPort: 8092
- name: third
containerPort: 8093
- name: forth
containerPort: 8094
- name: fifth
containerPort: 8085
- name: last
containerPort: 11210`

Once I apply my deployment to the cluster with the command kubectl apply -f couchbase-cluster.yaml, the pod starts.
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
couchbase-597ddbf7b9-bhwjl   1/1     Running   0          93s

And checking my container logs I have this:
kubectl logs couchbase-597ddbf7b9-bhwjl
Starting Couchbase Server – Web UI available at http://:8091
and logs available in /opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/logs

However while trying to exec into my pod to check other logs (kubectl exec -it couchbase-597ddbf7b9-bhwjl – /bin/bash), I find these errors (couchbase logs present at location /opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/logs)
couchbase.log:
[couchdb:info,2024-05-18T21:28:10.418Z,couchdb_ns_1@cb.local:couch_audit<0.284.0>:couch_log:info:30]Unable to connect to memcahced: {error,{badmatch,{error,econnrefused}}}.
[couchdb:error,2024-05-18T21:28:10.418Z,couchdb_ns_1@cb.local:couch_audit<0.284.0>:couch_log:error:33]Error in sending log messsage to memcached Reason: no_socket

error.log:
[ns_server:error,2024-05-18T21:33:17.318Z,ns_1@cb.local:memcached_config_mgr<0.19772.0>:memcached_config_mgr:push_tls_config:237]Failed to push TLS config to memcached: couldnt_connect_to_memcached
[ns_server:error,2024-05-18T21:33:21.341Z,ns_1@cb.local:prometheus_cfg<0.19154.0>:prometheus_cfg:terminate:544]Terminate: shutdown

memcached.log:
2024-05-18T21:33:21.709373+00:00 INFO ---------- Opening logfile:
2024-05-18T21:33:21.710194+00:00 INFO Couchbase version 7.2.5-7596 starting.
2024-05-18T21:33:21.710212+00:00 INFO Process identifier: 4375
2024-05-18T21:33:21.710223+00:00 INFO recalculate_max_connections: {“engine_fds”:1073675759,“max_connections”:65000,“max_fds”:1073741816,“system_connections”:5000}
2024-05-18T21:33:21.710266+00:00 INFO Breakpad enabled. Minidumps will be written to ‘/opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/crash’
2024-05-18T21:33:21.710302+00:00 INFO Fine clock overhead: 21ns
2024-05-18T21:33:21.710319+00:00 INFO Coarse clock overhead: 6ns)
2024-05-18T21:33:21.710330+00:00 INFO (Clock measurement period: 1ns)
2024-05-18T21:33:21.710523+00:00 INFO Using SLA configuration: {“COMPACT_DB”:{“slow”:“1800 s”},“CREATE_BUCKET”:{“slow”:“5 s”},“DELETE_BUCKET”:{“slow”:“10 s”},“SELECT_BUCKET”:{“slow”:“10 ms”},“SEQNO_PERSISTENCE”:{“slow”:“30 s”},“comment”:“Current MCBP SLA configuration”,“default”:{“slow”:“500 ms”},“version”:1}
2024-05-18T21:33:21.710535+00:00 INFO Enable standard input listener
2024-05-18T21:33:21.710584+00:00 INFO NUMA: Not available - not setting mem policy.
2024-05-18T21:33:21.710596+00:00 INFO Loading RBAC configuration from [/opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/config/memcached.rbac]
2024-05-18T21:33:21.710636+00:00 INFO Loading error maps from [/opt/couchbase/etc/couchbase/kv/error_maps]
2024-05-18T21:33:21.711310+00:00 INFO Prometheus Exporter started, listening on family:inet port:11280
2024-05-18T21:33:21.711325+00:00 INFO Starting external authentication manager
2024-05-18T21:33:21.715214+00:00 WARNING Failed to create audit thread
2024-05-18T21:33:21.715239+00:00 CRITICAL FATAL: Failed to start audit daemon
2024-05-18T21:33:21.715706+00:00 INFO ---------- Closing logfile

Why is it happening? I am not able to port forward properly to setup the cluster on UI too.
I think the couchbase server has not started properly but not sure what is wrong.
Kindly help! Please let me know if any other details are needed.

It looks like memcached is failing to start. I would expect there are further details in other log files.
2024-05-18T21:33:21.715239+00:00 CRITICAL FATAL: Failed to start audit daemon
